# Why is my TesNG is executing only first test class? is it something about calling same class more than once? Please see xml

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, testng.xml

I am trying to keep my login logout related test in single class. I am expecting to able to call them as and when needed in testing flow using include method tag in testng xml.

Everything was fine until I added logout method from same class. Now testng only executes first means launchapp test only.

```
<suite name="Temp Test Suite" parallel="false">

<test name="Temp Test">

    <classes preserve-order="true">

        <class name="commonTest.testclass.LaunchApp"/>

        <class name="commonTest.testclass.Login">
            <methods>
                <include name="normalLogin" />
            </methods>
        </class>            

        <class name="SmokeTest.testclass.Order" />
        <class name="SmokeTest.testclass.Checkout" />

        <class name="commonTest.testclass.Login">
            <methods>
                <include name="logout" />
            </methods>
        </class>

        <class name="commonTest.testclass.Login">
            <methods>
                <include name="adminLogin" />
            </methods>
        </class>

       <class name="SmokeTest.testclass.Order" />

       <class name="commonTest.testclass.Login">
            <methods>
                <include name="logout" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>      
</test>
```

Here is what actual class looks like (I have removed stuff for obvious reasons)

```
public class Login extends BaseTest
{
@BeforeClass
private void beforeClass()
{
    //does before stuff
}

@Test
public void normalLogin()
{


    //login
    loginPage.doLogin(Data.get("Login"), Data.get("Password"));

    loginPage.clickOkButton();

    //check if dashboard page is opened
    Assert.assertTrue(commonPage.isVisible());
}

@Test
public void adminLogin()
{
    //login
    loginPage.doLogin(Data.get("Login"), Data.get("Password"));

    loginPage.clickOkButton();

    //check if dashboard page is opened
    Assert.assertTrue(commonPage.isVisible());
}

@Test
public void logout()
{
    //login
    loginPage.doLogout();

    Assert.assertTrue(loginPage.isVisible());
}

@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) 
{
    //does after stuff
}
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of the class you are executing from the testng file

Comment: class is added now

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<test name="Temp Test">

<classes preserve-order="true">

       <class name="com.aris.client.apiportal.test.web.latest.LaunchApp"/>
       <class name="com.aris.client.apiportal.test.web.latest.loginTest">
             <methods>
                 <include name="normalLogin"/>
                 <include name="logOut"/>
                 <include name="adminLogin"/>
             </methods>
       </class>
</classes>      
</test>
```

Comment: Testng XML is not only about login and logout. Sorry if my original question gave you that impression. I have edited the questions. In this case combining like you have mentioned above wont be compatible.